# Passing request headers to HttpWebRequest in C#

Tags: c#, json, get, http-headers, httprequest

I am trying to make a HttpWebRequest and get json data from it. Using Postman, when I set url, parameters & headers, I am able to get json response (please see [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HU15R6gdRGSkFvXzRzaHM5RFU/view?usp=sharing)). But, using C# when I try, I do not get anything in response.

I searched a couple of posts on Stackoverflow and followed the steps, but cannot find what is wrong or if anything else is required.

```
        string requestUrl = Constants.FLIPKART_INSTALLS_URL;
        requestUrl = requestUrl.Replace("##STARTDATE##", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        requestUrl = requestUrl.Replace("##ENDDATE##", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        //request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = "GET";
        //request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Headers["Fk-Affiliate-id"] = Constants.FLIPKART_AFFILIATE_ID;
        request.Headers["Fk-Affiliate-token"] = Constants.FLIPKART_AFFILIATE_TOKEN;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_HU15R6gdRGTnJRclZPQVVxWmM/view?usp=sharing) is the response that I get. I am not sure if this is really a silly question, but since I don't have much knowledge of C#, therefore I posted it. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `GetResponse` does not return a string, see the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) that shows how to use `GetResponseStream` and actually read it as text.

Comment: Thank You Alex, I am reading it! Will let you know if this solves my issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex, I am getting -1 in Content-length in the response, does that signifies something is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling GetResponseStream() on the response object, I was able to read the contents, refer below code if needed:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public class Test
{
    // Specify the URL to receive the request.
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create (args[0]);

        // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
        request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
        // Set credentials to use for this request.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

        Console.WriteLine ("Content length is {0}", response.ContentLength);
        Console.WriteLine ("Content type is {0}", response.ContentType);

        // Get the stream associated with the response.
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

        // Pipes the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader (receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);

        Console.WriteLine ("Response stream received.");
        Console.WriteLine (readStream.ReadToEnd ());
        response.Close ();
        readStream.Close ();
    }
}
```